# Will the Product of a Set of Primes above 1 ever be Equal to The Product of a Different Set of Primes above 1

Tags: prime-numbers

Given two sets `a` and `b`. When `a` and `b` only contain primes above 1, will the product of every number in `a` ever be equivalent to the product of every number in `b`?

Comment: As those are *sets* if they are different then there is at least one element in one of them which is not in the other one. Now just apply the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: The [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) assures us that if the products of two sets of primes are equal, the sets are identical.

Comment: If the sets are different, then there is at least one prime which belongs in one set but not in the other. Hence one product will be divisible by that prime and one product will not. Hence the answer to your question is No. For multi-sets, it is slightly (but not extremely) more difficult to show a similar argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's see about that, let

\begin{align}
 N=\prod_{p \in a} p, \\
 M=\prod_{r \in b} r.
\end{align}

If $N=M$, then the fundamental theorem of arithmetic tells us that $M$ and $N$ both have the same prime factors, i.e., if $p \in a$ then also $p \in b$ and vice versa. Therefore $N=M$ implies $a=b$

Comment: Thanks, to you along with all the people in the comments.